# Xamarin 4.0.12 generated .apk not installing on device

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using xamarin 4.0.12 for android development. My problem is when i ren the app on device it gets run normally but if i install the generated apk file the it could not install on device.I made debugging for this issue and ring that xamarin is giving an error for resource file:Package CalenderDemo.CalenderDemo has no certificates at entry res/drawable/icon.png; ignoring!
Please suggest something , any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Could you post a logcat of when the error occurs?

Comment: Did you follow: [preparing app for release](http://goo.gl/0GNkdS) ?

Answer (score 1):

I work with Xamarin.Forms and had a similar problem.
In my case, the problem was, tat **no classes.dex** was included in my .apk.
**This was, because I had not set the Java Max Heap Size to 1G in my Android-project-settings.**